# Size of user-defined datatypes and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let's say we have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A 
{
    int x =1;
};

struct B: public A{};
struct C: public A{};
struct D: public A{
    B b;
    C c;

};

int main()
{
    cout<<sizeof(D);

    return 0;
}
```

When i run this program, it turns out that size of struct D is 12, which is the same as if i had three integer data types. Considering the fact that D inherited only one x from struct A and that her own data members are objects of classes(structs to be precise) derived from A in similar fashion, which makes sense.

However, when i add this following line to the code inside class D

```
virtual void f(){};
```

i get value 24, which means that size of struct D doubled just by adding this method into it. I see that this is virtual method, but i don't see how that affects this struct in terms of it's size considering the fact that it just makes polymorhism possible in case i derive a class out of D, which is not something that happened here. What is actually going on here? Any help appreciated!

Now, when i add this line of code to my struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual functions and polymorphism might cause the compiler to add compiler and implementation specific hidden data to your structures. The most common method is to use a [*virtual table* (a.k.a. vtable)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) of function pointers. This table takes up space inside the structure itself, usually by the size of a pointer.

Considering your example of `24` bytes in total, I guess you're on a 32-bit system where pointers are 4 bytes (32 bits), as 12 plus 4 times 3 is equal to 24.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, how can i know the size of class when i have virtual functions in general, will it always double the size i have or will it always add 12 bytes or something else? In fact, i use 64bit Win7. But i compiled this in an online compiler

Comment: @cdummie Each class in the inheritance hierarchy will add their own vtable to the object, so the size depends on how many parent classes there are. If you use virtual functions and don't know how many parent classes there are, then you simply can't use `sizeof` to determine the size of the objects. Besides, the size of a structure (or class) can be deceptive, for example `sizeof` of a `std::string` is *not* equal to the length of the string. And you also consider [padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member).

Comment: So basically, if we ignore padding, we can say that for each parent class we have 4 more bytes?

Comment: @cdummie On a 32-bit system, and with a compiler which implements vtables that way.